# How to write two variables in one line?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

I would like to write two variable in a file. I mean this is my code :

```
file.write("a = %g\n" %(params[0]))
file.write("b = %g\n" %(params[1]))
```

and what I want to write in my file is :

```
f(x) = ax + b
```

where `a` is `params[0]` and `b` is `params[1]` but I don't know how to do this ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: you should look at the `format` string method

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to write to your file is `f(x) = ax + b` where `a` and `b` are `params[0]` and `params[1]`, respectively, just do this:

```
file.write('f(x) = %gx + %g\n' % (params[0], params[1]))
```

`'f(x) = %gx + %g' % (params[0], params[1])` is simply string formatting, where you're putting `a` and `b` in their correct spaces.

Edit: If you're using Python 3.6, you can use f-strings:

```
a, b = params[0], params[1]
file.write(f'f(x) = {a}x + {b}\n')
```

Comment: Does `file.write()` automatically add a newline?

Comment: From reading the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper), I didn't see anything indicating that a newline is automatically written. So you'd have to add the `'\n'` character at the end of the string.

Comment: That's my point -- you forgot the newline.

Comment: I thought I sensed a hint of a rhetorical question there :)

Answer (score 0):

```
"f(x) = {a}x + {b}".format(a=params[0], b=params[1])
```

Is a clean solution

Answer (score 0):

sorry I don't know Python, but I guess this

```
f = open('file', 'w')
x = 0;
a = 0;
b = 0;
result = a*x+b
a = str(a)
b = str(b)
x = str(x)
result = str(result)
f.write("f("+x+")="+result) #this is if you want result to be shown
print("f("+x+")="+result)

#or

f.write("f("+x+")="+a+""+x+"+"+b) #this is if you want actually show f(x)= ax+b
print("f("+x+")="+a+""+x+"+"+b)
```

again I don't know Python, but this is what I come up with by using : https://repl.it/HARP/1

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You target is to achieve is to write the equation below to be written inside the file.

`f(x) = ax + b where a is params[0] and b is params[1]`

What you should do is

```
file.write('f(x) = %gx + %g' % (param[0], param[1]))
```

which will write

```
"f(x) = 2x + 3" # if params[0] and params[1] are 2 and 3 resp
```

What you are doing is

```
file.write("a = %g\n" %(params[0]))
file.write("b = %g\n" %(params[1]))
```

This will write in the file as:

```
a = 2
b = 3
```

if params[0] and params[1] are 2 and 3 respectively